# Unable to find 128 bit characteristic UUID using Zephyr Heart Rate Service

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, zephyr-rtos, nordic-semi

I'm using the zephyr heart rate service in the exact same manner as it is used in the Peripheral HR Sample. I need the 128 bit service and characteristic UUID's for the application I am using it with.

I believe I was able to find the Service UUID using a BLE scanner app, it showed that the device UUID is 427A193D-7F82-E25F-822D-0C3B2CC69F19.

I cannot find the 128 bit characteristic UUID anywhere, please advise.

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/samples/bluetooth/peripheral_hr/README.html

https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/main/samples/bluetooth/peripheral_hr/src/main.c

Comment: The code you've linked says it's advertising heart rate service (0x180d), battery service (0x180f), and device information service (0x180a). These are all documented BLE services (see bluetooth.org). I'm not certain where you're getting this 128-bit service UUID. Which service are you looking for? (To find an advertised characteristic, though, you'd connect with a tool like nRF Connect and query the device for its services and characteristics.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.